# Using angular2/4 material, How to use mat-chip with text next to chips on each row?

Tags: html, css, angular

Using angular2/4, I want to use mat-chip (https://material.angular.io/components/chips/overview) with text next to a single chip and have that take up the whole width for each 'entry' (a single line in a div). Additional entries should be displayed underneath each other like a running chat. Right now I have:

My current code is as follows, but it doesn't look like it is achieving the expected result...

```
<div class="rectanglebox" style="width:300px;height:500px;">
<div style="float:left">
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip>A</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</div>
<div style="float:left">Text for A that is really long and may overflow. If it does, the chip should remain to the left side and not move all the text to a new dedicated line.</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip>B</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</div>
<div style="float:left">Text for B</div>
</div>
<div style="float:left">
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip>C</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</div>
<div style="float:left">Text for C</div>
</div>
```

Uodated with sample that shows how all the text is going "below" the chip if it is too long instead of wrapping around it:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijhhz3-fn56yj?file=app/chips-overview-example.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `style="display: inline-block"` for a div which you want to show, I have modified your HTML you can check here, to fixed div you need to use postion property of css. I have used `position: absolute` to learn more you can check [here](http://www.wickham43.net/divboxes.php)

```
 <div class="rectanglebox" style="width:300px;height:500px;">
<div style="display: inline-block;position: absolute;">
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip>A</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 45px;">Text for A where something is super long that ehrere sids sdis fdf ds f sdf sd fs d fs fsd f s fsd f sf df s fs fd Text for A where something is super long that ehrere sids sdis fdf ds f sdf sd fs d fs fsd f s fsd f sf df s fs fd Text for C long that ehrere sids sdis fdf ds f sdf sd fs d fs fsd f s fsd f sf df s fs fd margin-left: 45px;</div>

<div>
<div style="display: inline-block;position: absolute;">
<mat-chip-list aria-orientation="vertical"> 
  <mat-chip>B</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 45px;">Text for B Text for A where something is super long that ehrere sids sdis fdf ds f sdf sd fs d fs fsd f s fsd f sf df s fs fd margin-left: 45px;</div>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;position: absolute;">
<mat-chip-list>
  <mat-chip>C</mat-chip>
</mat-chip-list>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;margin-left: 45px;" >Text for C long that ehrere sids sdis fdf ds f sdf sd fs d fs fsd f s fsd f sf df s fs fd margin-left: 45px;</div>
</div>
```

have a look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijhhz3-yahv46?file=app/chips-overview-example.html)

Comment: Issue with this is if "Text for A" becomes really long, all the text goes to the next line and the chip becomes aligned to the middle. Is there a way to make it so that the chip always stay to the left and all the text in the div does not jump below the chip?

Comment: Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijhhz3-fn56yj?file=app/chips-overview-example.html

Comment: Hi you need to set position for your div position will fixed, absolute your div, i have used absolute to set position for div A. you can check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijhhz3-yahv46?file=app/chips-overview-example.html

Comment: This works, though requires the 'chip' to be no more than a specific width, otherwise have to change margins. Is it safe to say there is no way to adjust based on width of chip?

Comment: yes, you can also adjust depending on chips width. for that, you need to set text width also.